# Zeppelin: Need to know more about zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have recently started learning zeppelin. I know we can use angular and PostgreSQL e.t.c within it using interpreter. I have gone through its tutorial as well. But it is not as descriptive as I thought. I have many doubts which I am asking to you and which may help other beginners as well.

1> How we can create API for the zeppelin (if possible)?: As most of the client side apps uses API, is it possible to create API in zeppelin ? and in which language we can create API. If possible I am thinking to create API in java or node.js(JS).

2> Is it possible to integrate zeppelin graphs in any UI(angular or html ?)?

3> How we can deploy zeppelin based application in production environment ?

If you have any good tutorial source please attach it.

If I have asked unrelated questions please point out. I will change it.

Thanks in advance for provide help and giving you precious time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Apache Zeppelin has wide and well described API [1]. You can use any language to work with API.
2. Yes [2]. You can embed the paragraph result to your website.
3. You can use binary package or built from source [3].
   [4] contains a lot of code in setup section.

--

1. http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/rest_api/notebook.html
2. http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/other_features/publishing_paragraphs.html
3. http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/quickstart/install.html
4. http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/